# to loop two arrays in the ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs

I have two arrays one in recommendation Name which I like to show as a hyperlink and second is recommendation ID which I want to pass in the URL, but in Html, if I am using ng-repeat on the recommendation Name then I cannot see the value of recommendation Id and vice -versa.

My codes are:

Controller.js:

```
    function viewRecommendationCtrl($scope,$http,$state)
    {
        $http.get('/viewRecommendations')
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.recoName = data.recoName;
            $scope.recoId = data.recoId;  
            console.log($scope.recoName);
            console.log($scope.recoId);
    })
}
```

HTML code is:

```
<div ng-controller="viewRecommendationCtrl">
    <ul ng-repeat="reco in recoName">
        <li><a href = "/#/company/AddRecommendation/{{recoId}}">{{reco}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The data format is: for recoName

```
0: "Great"
1: "UTKARSH"
2: "Physical working place for R&D and manufacturting team"
3: "Define a standard operating process (SOP) for R&D team"
4: "Legal Compliance as per the Government of India (GOI) rules"
```

for recoId:

```
0: {low: 4, high: 0}
1: {low: 5, high: 0}
2: {low: 1, high: 0}
3: {low: 2, high: 0}
4: {low: 3, high: 0}
```

So what should be the code?

Thanks

Comment: Can't you incorporate your recoId in your recoName like [{recoName: "Great", recoId:[{low:4,high:0}]}].... like this?

Comment: @iswar it can be in one array which defines the both recoName and recoId

Comment: is not the best practice but, if you recoName is same index as recoId, you can use the property `$index` of ng-repeat to get the recoId. If you can make in a single array like Iswar suggested it would be way easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the index of the array `$index`.

```
<div ng-controller="viewRecommendationCtrl">
    <ul ng-repeat="reco in recoName">
        <li><a href = "/#/company/AddRecommendation/{{recoId[$index]}}">{{recoId[$index].low}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is working, but I have to show the value in the low field of the recoId, so if I am using the recoId.low[$index] is not working.

Comment: Bind the value as `recoId[$index].low`. I have edited the answer